# App widget listview design gets change when loading dynamic image using url android

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

Hi I'm using widget listview. I want to load image on each widget listview item so I have used below code to load image using url

```
 public class ListProvider implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {

private String TAG = ListProvider.class.getSimpleName();
private Context context = null;
private UserPreference userPreference;
private int appWidgetId;
private String feedsData, mLaneName, mLaneId;
private Tooteet.Collection collection;
private ArrayList<Item> mItems;

public ListProvider(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;
    userPreference = new UserPreference(context);
    appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    feedsData = intent.getStringExtra(LargeWidgetProvider.LARGE_WIDGET_LIST_DATA);
    mLaneId = intent.getStringExtra(LargeWidgetProvider.WIDGET_LANE_ID);
    mLaneName = intent.getStringExtra(LargeWidgetProvider.WIDGET_LANE_NAME);

    if(mLaneId != null && mLaneName != null) {
        collection = new Tooteet.Collection(feedsData, mLaneId, mLaneName);
    }
    mItems = getItems(collection);
}

public ArrayList<Item> getItems(Tooteet.Collection collection) {
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    if (collection == null) {
        return items;
    }

    int sectionFirstPosition = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for (Tooteet tooteet : collection.getItems()) {
        int type = tooteet.getTweetType();
        int viewType = VIEW_TYPE_TEXT;
        switch (type) {
            case TooteetType.TEXT:
            case TooteetType.NOTE:
                viewType = VIEW_TYPE_TEXT;
                // add text;
                break;
            case TooteetType.PICTURE:
            case TooteetType.DRAWING:
            case TooteetType.VIDEO:
                viewType = VIEW_TYPE_MEDIA;
                // add media
                break;
            case TooteetType.AUDIO:
            case TooteetType.DOCUMENT:
                //case TooteetType.EXPENSE:
                viewType = VIEW_TYPE_FILE;
                // add file
                break;
            case TooteetType.MEASURE:
                viewType = VIEW_TYPE_MEASURE;
                break;
            case TooteetType.EXPENSE:
                viewType = VIEW_TYPE_EXPENSE;
                break;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "getItems   -- tooteet: "+tooteet);
        items.add(new Item("", false, tooteet, viewType, sectionFirstPosition, i));
        i++;
    }
    return items;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    Log.d(TAG, " getCount() -- mItems.size(): "+mItems.size());
    return mItems.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

/*
 *Similar to getView of Adapter where instead of View
 *we return RemoteViews
 *
 */
@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(final int position) {
    Log.d(TAG,"=============getViewAt   position=========="+position);
    RemoteViews remoteView = null;
    final Item item = mItems.get(position);

    if (item.mTooteet.getTweetType() == TooteetType.TEXT || item.mTooteet.getTweetType() == TooteetType.NOTE) {
        remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_feed_list_text);
        remoteView.setImageViewResource(R.id.feed_type,R.drawable.feed_list_note);
    } else if (item.mTooteet.getTweetType() == TooteetType.PICTURE || item.mTooteet.getTweetType() == TooteetType.DRAWING  || item.mTooteet.getTweetType() == TooteetType.VIDEO) {
        remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_feed_list_image);
        int drawable = R.drawable.feed_list_attachment;
        if (item.mTooteet.getTweetType() == TooteetType.PICTURE) {
            drawable = R.drawable.feed_list_picture;
        } else if (item.mTooteet.getTweetType() == TooteetType.VIDEO) {
            drawable = R.drawable.feed_list_video;
        }else if(item.mTooteet.getTweetType() == TooteetType.DRAWING){
            drawable = R.drawable.feed_list_drawing;
        }
        remoteView.setImageViewResource(R.id.feed_type,drawable);
        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        final RemoteViews finalRemoteView1 = remoteView;
        uiHandler.post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Picasso.with(context).load(item.mTooteet.getThumbUrl1()).into(
                        finalRemoteView1, R.id.feed_image,
                        new int[]{appWidgetId});
            }
        });
    }  else if (item.mTooteet.getTweetType() == TooteetType.AUDIO || item.mTooteet.getTweetType() == TooteetType.DOCUMENT) {
        remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_feed_list_audio);
        int drawable;
        if (item.mTooteet.getTweetType() == TooteetType.AUDIO) {
            drawable = R.drawable.feed_list_audio;
        } else {
            drawable = FeedDocResourceHandler.getIconResForListDoc(item.mTooteet.getUniqueFileName());
        }
        remoteView.setImageViewResource(R.id.feed_type,drawable);
    } else if (item.mTooteet.getTweetType() == TooteetType.MEASURE) {
        remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_feed_list_measure);
    }else if (item.mTooteet.getTweetType() == TooteetType.EXPENSE) {
        remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_feed_list_expense);
    }

    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.feed_keywords, item.mTooteet.getKeywords());

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.mTooteet.getTooteetText())){
        remoteView.setViewVisibility(R.id.feed_text, View.VISIBLE);
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.feed_text, item.mTooteet.getTooteetText());
    }else{
        remoteView.setViewVisibility(R.id.feed_text, View.GONE);
    }

    if (!item.mTooteet.isLocationEmpty()) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.mTooteet.getLocationString())) {
            remoteView.setViewVisibility(R.id.feed_location, View.VISIBLE);
            remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.feed_location, item.mTooteet.getLocationString());
        } else {
            final RemoteViews finalRemoteView = remoteView;
            ReverseGeocoder.with(Constants.getLanesApp()).load(item.mTooteet, new com.kwypesoft.lanes.location.GeocodeApi.OnLocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(String location) {
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(location)) {
                        finalRemoteView.setViewVisibility(R.id.feed_location, View.VISIBLE);
                        finalRemoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.feed_location, item.mTooteet.getLocationString());
                        item.mTooteet.setLocationString(location);
                    }else{
                        finalRemoteView.setViewVisibility(R.id.feed_location, View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }else{
        remoteView.setViewVisibility(R.id.feed_location, View.GONE);
    }

    final Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
    fillInIntent.setAction(LargeWidgetProvider.ACTION_TOAST);
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(LargeWidgetProvider.WIDGET_LANE_ID, mLaneId);
    bundle.putSerializable(DetailBase.FEED_DETAILS, item.mTooteet);
    fillInIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    remoteView.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.root, fillInIntent);
    return remoteView;
}


@Override
public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 5;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
}

@Override
public void onDataSetChanged() {
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
}

private static class Item{
    boolean isHeader;
    String header;
    public Tooteet mTooteet;
    int viewType;
    int firstPosition;
    int itemPosition;

    public Item(String header, boolean isHeader, Tooteet tooteet, int type, int firstPosition, int itemPosition) {
        this.header = header;
        this.isHeader = isHeader;
        mTooteet = tooteet;
        this.viewType = type;
        this.firstPosition = firstPosition;
        this.itemPosition = itemPosition;
    }
}
```

}

But this will change my widget UI design and it shows only one listview item at a time.

where i have only one appWidgetId in listview provider class which extends RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory. I do not know. What's went wrong. Could you please suggest me a idea to fix it?

Comment: could you please post your adapter code?

Comment: @Ahamed I have posted please check it and let me know your comments.

Comment: @Ahamed Any clue's?

Answer (score 0):

Picasso offers much more than just downloading image. It can resize the image, transform before it is displayed in ImageView. So you can resize or transform your image as follow.

```
Picasso.with(this)
     .load("YOUR IMAGE URL HERE")               
     .error(R.drawable.ic_error_fallback)      // optional        
     .resize(250, 200)                        // optional        
     .rotate(90)                             // optional        
     .into(imageView);
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have fix my issue using Universal image loader like below,

```
public class YourViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory
{
 Map<Integer, Boolean> flags = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>());
 Bitmap mBitmap;
 Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());


  @Override
  public RemoteViews getViewAt(final int position)
{
  final RemoteViews row = new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(), R.layout.row);
  flags.put(position, false);
  handler.post(new Runnable()
  {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        m_imgLoader.loadImage(YOUR_IMAGE_URL, new SimpleImageLoadingListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason)
            {
                flags.put(position, true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view)
            {
                flags.put(position, true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String arg0, View arg1, Bitmap bitmap)
            {
                mBitmap = bitmap;
                flags.put(position, true);
            }
        });
    }
});

while (!flags.get(position))
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
flags.put(position, false);
if (mBitmap != null)
{
    row.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.ivPoster, mBitmap);
} else
{
    row.setImageViewResource(R.id.ivPoster, R.drawable.cw);
}
mBitmap = null;
  } // End of getViewAt override


} // End of class
```

Please make use of it.